# Periodic notification with Pusher

Tags: ruby-on-rails, cron, push-notification, pusher

I have a queue of messages that must be displayed to the user **every two minutes**, **one at a time**.

Does Pusher have a cron feature?

An example of the desired behavior:

**00:00** – **User_A** sends **Message_A** and it is enqueued. Once the queue is empty, **Message_A** is delivered immediately.

**00:30** - **User_B** sends **Message_B** and it is enqueued.

**02:00** - **????** checks the queue and uses Push (or other websocket service) to deliver **Message_B**

I need the **????** piece.

Answer (score 0):

No, Pusher doesn't offer a cron feature.

But, it would be easy to use a service like [iron.io](http://iron.io) and then hit your own endpoint every two minutes and from that endpoint publish to Pusher.

See:

- [IronMQ Push Queues](http://blog.iron.io/2013/01/ironmq-push-queues-reliable-message.html)
- [Add Messages to a Queue docs](http://dev.iron.io/mq/reference/api/#add_messages_to_a_queue) - specifically the 'delay'. This means you can define when you want the message to be queued and effectively published.

Comment: Do I need a worker to make the hitting? I don't found this on iron.io docs.

Comment: I've added a link to the overview blog post which links to the docs.

Comment: In the post's example the messages are delivered to client as soon as they are received. I want to process the deliveries every two minutes. Do I missing something? Thanks!